# Access iphone setting preference

Tags: iphone

I would like to access smtp outgoing mail server address from global setting->mail->accounts->outgoing mail server. Is there any public API available now to get the user global setting values?

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. There are undocumented keys for the NSUserDefaults class, but I'm not sure there's any that covers your problem, and on the other hand, any app released which uses them might be blocked by the App Store review team.