# Access iOS settings from code

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Programatically access iPhone System Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150321/programatically-access-iphone-system-setting)
>   [How do I access the iPhone's settings from my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655887/how-do-i-access-the-iphones-settings-from-my-code)
>   [How to access iPhone general accessibility settings with OS 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591720/how-to-access-iphone-general-accessibility-settings-with-os-4-0)
>   [How to access iPhone's general accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175624/how-to-access-iphones-general-accessibility-settings)
>   [iPhone Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333736/iphone-settings)
>   [Access iphone setting preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152873/access-iphone-setting-preference)

Is there a way to, from my code query the iOS settings app for a certain setting? For example I want to know if "Multitasking Gestures" is turned on or not? Or even be able to change the settings?(From my research it seems like I definitely cant do this)

Comment: @kaveman: What are you talking about? From the other question: "I want to be able to read the values a user has set in the built-in "Settings" app of the iPhone." This question: "Is there a way to, from my code query the iOS settings app for a certain setting?" That's only one of a handful at least -- Krishnabhadra links another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In general, you can read your own app's preferences (whether they're set via the Settings app or by your app) using NSUserDefaults. You cannot, however, read the preferences for other applications, including system settings. There may be cases where you can figure out what the setting must be by using API specific to that setting, but in such cases you still shouldn't assume that you know what selection the user has made in the Settings app.