# Opening iCloud.app in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios5

How to open iCloud.app in my own iPhone application?  The only information I have ables me to open Setting.app through this line of code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

but I want to check if the calender is on/off in iCloud on the iPhone.
So when I run my own application I want to move directly in iCloud through my application.

How to access iCloud in iPhone applications?

Comment: sir i want to check calender option is on/off in icloud , how to check this case by objective c code in my application ,while this link only open [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]]; setting.app in my application i required i move to icloud setting directly when i run  my application

Comment: i want to open setting->general->icloud and check calender on/off with the help of objective c  code .please suggest me

Comment: [you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7328656/251513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such app as the iCloud app. I presume you are talking about the iCloud menu in the settings app, there was a brief time in iOS 5.0 where you could use the `prefs://` URL scheme to access menus in the settings app, however Apple disabled that in the very next update.

Hopefully it wills return in the future, but even if it does there will still be no way to programmatically determine the status of settings (such as icloud calendar sync) or manipulate the settings.