# is it possible to get device settings on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

android allows u to get a complete system settings dump using dumpsys or the getprop shell commands. there are also the android.provider.settings and android.provider.secure APIs that allow us to get a lot of android device data such as bluetooth and wifi settings etc.

is there any such way to do so on iOS. as far as i have researched there are separate APIs for most things like bluetooth which need a lot of hunting...

Answer (score 3):

Apple's official public APIs do not allow an iOS app to access General settings in the Settings app, such as the wifi enable. NSUserDefaults only allows access to those preferences and settings created specifically by that one app for its own use.

But some settings, by using a private API you can access them. However, apparently, using these private API's prevents your app from being accepted into the app store. A Link: [Access iOS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328545/access-ios-settings-from-code) from code.

Comment: i dont want to use the private APIs. i dont want to edit these settings. Is not even just checking the current setting possible??

Comment: i found some answers to this but wanted to confirm once..getting the phone RAM, memory, Processor type etc is also not possible in case of iOS, is it?

Comment: Yes this type of settings not possible into the IOS application but it is possible when the device is jailbreak and not upload on to the apple store this type of the application upload on the jailbreak stores.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 5.0 i was opening Twitter setting from my app . if you want to access Twitter you can do it by :

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];

but , this features is removed in iOS 5.1 , hence i can not able to open twitter setting .

This link help you too. :[How to open preferences/settings with iOS 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-preferences-settings-with-ios-5-1/13027427#13027427)