# are lock screen notifications enabled on iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, lockscreen

Is there an iOS API ( either public or private) using which i can check if viewing notifications on the lock screen is enabled or disabled?

i just want to read the setting to check if notifications are enabled and make no changes to it.

Comment: also is there any way to check if the 'ERASE DATA' setting for excessive password failures is enabled?

Comment: I (and probably most users) am very interested in the "public API" part of this question.  `UIRemoteNotificationType` takes you most of the way, but doesn't include the lock screen setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to read setting with private api but if you use it then it will not be allowed in the AppStore. [Access iOS settings from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328545/access-ios-settings-from-code)

Comment: Thanks, but i have been thru that post. do you know the exact api that can help me read this particular setting? I am cool with using private API too!

Comment: That link is not useful because it doesn't actually document any API.  Maybe it used to contain that info?  As a result, currently this isn't really an answer.